# Apache2 throwing 500 error for php files. log shows Premature end of script headers

Tags: php, apache, apache2, localhost

I'm on a relatively fresh install of Ubuntu and this is the first time I've used the local web server on it.

The problem I have is that when I try and access a php file I get a 500 error.

To try and solve it I've:

> - Renamed index.html to index.php in  /var/www to make sure it's not a virtualhost error (standard "it works" file)
> - given 0777 permissions to both /var/www and the index.php file
> - made www-data the owner of the directory and the file
> - made www-data the group for the directory and the file
> - checked the error log
> - trawled Google

The error log shows:

> [Sat Sep 07 13:18:56 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

which I understand means the PHP is loading correctly

The only entry I do not understand is

> [Sat Sep 07 13:19:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of
>   script headers: index.php

I've done searches but most of the articles I've found are no help.

Is there anything else I can do to try to debug the error or does anybody have any ideas as to why this error is happening?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Is error reporting on in php?
try adding:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

on the first line of the script after

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you're answer, I can't tell you if it works or not as I've just solved the problem (more details below). Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for VIVEK-MDU for the suggestions and changes to my post. I must admit that I thought the lists were done automatically (I never got into markdown (just seen I missed the space before the minus sign on the list items)).

Answer?
Unfortunately I cannot help anybody who lands at this page with a similar problem.

I also develop on my laptop which has a similar setup. after copying:

- /etc/apache2/
- /etc/hosts
- /var/www - the correct permissions for my system are my-user (not root or www-data)

The system now works as expected. Again: sorry I can't help anybody else but thanks to everyone who looked and the people that helped.
John